# What is the transitive closure of the following digraph?

Tags: graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

What is the transitive closure of the following digraph ? To find reach-ability matrix and adjacency matrix.

[image]

**My approach:**

The adjacency matrix is \begin{bmatrix} 0 &1 &0 &0 \\ 0 & 0&0 &1 \\ 0 & 0 &0 &0 \\1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.

Using Warshall's  algorithm, the reach-ability  matrix  for  transitive  closure  is  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 &1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1& 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.

So the transitive closure is the graph:
[image]

**Am I right  ?**

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite.  Here's the transitive closure graph:

[image]

Recall that the transitive closure of graph $g$ has the same vertices as $g$ but with (directed) edges between vertices $u$ and $v$ if there is a path—any path—between $u$ and $v$ in $g$.  Just examine your graph and you can construct the transitive closure "by hand."  Notice, for instance, there is no path from $c$ to $b$ in $g$... and hence no edge between those vertices in the transitive closure graph.  But there *is* a (long) path from $a$ to $c$ in $g$, and hence there is an edge from $a$ to $c$ in the transitive closure.

You can check all the others...

---

A note to the specialist:  Transitive closures are most properly defined on directed acyclic graphs (DAGs).  If one admits cycles ("loops") then there will be some vertices with paths to themselves, and thus a transitive closure should include a "self loop."

Comment: I am confusing with adjacency matrix and transitive closure. Can please state the difference between them. Is the 2nd matrix a transitive closure or the 1st matrix above?

Comment: Why did you change the positions or the arrangement of the vertices ?

Comment: Vertex location is generally irrelevant in graph theory... but I replotted just for you.